# How to give a percentage change interpretation for diff-in-diff coefficient of interest?

Tags: econometrics, regression-coefficients, difference-in-difference, percentage

I'm doing a diff-in-diff to see whether a chosen regulation has an effect on goods exports. I got my coefficient of interest result as being -53,157.68, which would mean that this regulation caused a fall in exports by $5,315,768,000 for the treatment group (the export data was divided by 100,000). How can I get this result as a percentage change so that an easier interpretation of the result can be offered? e.g. the regulation led to a ...% fall in exported goods for the treatment group. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could run your regression on log-level.

Assuming that currently you are running regression like this:

$$ X_{it} = \alpha_i + \beta \tau_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

where $X$ following economics notation stands for exports and $\tau_{it}$ is your treatment.

you could run regression like this:

$$ \ln (X_{it} ) = \alpha_i + \beta \tau_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

in log-level form the $\beta$ coefficient can be interpreted as $\% \Delta X_{it}= 100\cdot\left( e^{\beta} -1\right)$, so in that case you could get into percentage change interpretation. However, note you should not apply natural logarithm to any variable, I assume here you measure exports as volume or in constant prices. For example, normally there would be even more direct way of getting to the percentage changes by estimating log-log form but it would not make sense to take log of treatment dummy.